# Quantum numbers for diatomic molecules

Tags: angular-momentum, symmetry, eigenvalue, molecules, quantum-states

A diatomic molecule:

[image: Blockquote]

is always symmetric if we rotate it along its internuclear axis. Let it be the z-axis.
Then we can say that $[{\cal \hat H}, {\hat L}_z] =0 $, so there is a common set of eigenstates that simultaneously diagonalize $\cal \hat H$ and ${\hat L}_z$.
The eigenvalue for $\hat L_z$ is in this case denoted with the Greek letter $\lambda$.

This leads us to one quantum number for diatomic molecules. It depends on the values $\lambda$
assumes (in general, what actually matters is $\Lambda = \sum_i \lambda_i$ if we deal with more complex molecules):

1. if $\Lambda = 0 $ the state is called $\Sigma$
2. if $|\Lambda| = 1 $ the state is called $\Pi$
3. if $|\Lambda| = 2 $ the state is called $\Delta$

There are a few things I don't understand:
Why is there $|\Lambda|$ and not $\Lambda$ itself? How do I get these values ($0, 1, 2$) from? Why are they the only possible ones for $\Lambda$?